# Module being imported from another Python install

Tags: python, powershell, python-3.4, windows-server-2012, python-venv

I'm running multiple installs of Python on Windows Server 2012. I can probably find a way to work around this, but I'm curious as to what is going on. I'm wary about radically changing the installs in case I break other people's Python scheduled tasks that I may not be aware of.

(All the code boxes below are PowerShell).

```
PS C:\> C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe list
jdcal (1.0)
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (12.0.5)
virtualenv (13.1.2)
```

Although this Python 3.4 install doesn't have Django installed, it appears to pick up the version from the Python 33x86 install. Is that normal?

```
PS C:\> C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.6.5
PS C:\> C:\Python33x86\python.exe -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.6.5
```

I've created a Python virtualenv based on Python 3.4 and installed Django 1.8.4 in it. Doing a "pip list" confirms that it is installed correctly:-

```
PS C:\> D:\PyVirtualEnvs\example_py34\Scripts\activate.bat
PS C:\> D:\PyVirtualEnvs\example_py34\Scripts\pip.exe list | Select-String "Django "
Django (1.8.4)
```

However, when I import within that virtualenv, I get Django version 1.6.5:-

```
PS C:\> D:\PyVirtualEnvs\example_py34\Scripts\python.exe -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.6.5
```

Is this a bug in virtualenv or am I missing something?

EDIT: Could it be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920265/python-module-imported-from-outside-virtualenv)?

EDIT2: The same thing happens when using [pyvenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), as suggested by ham-sandwich.

Comment: Maybe a daft question, but are you sure you have activated the venv? `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

Comment: Yes, at the top of the 3rd code box above. Saying that, there's no visual feedback when doing it to verify that it worked.

Comment: Is there a reason for using virtualenv, instead of pyvenv? https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv

Comment: @ham-sandwich - Oh, that's news to me. Thanks for the link, from the related PEP, it sounds good. However, my question above seems to run deeper than virtualenvs; I still find it surprising that 3.4 imports something from 3.3 and would like to know why.

Comment: Also one of our virtual envs was 2.7 and I think pyenv is 3.3+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the reason for this behaviour. The PYTHONPATH environment variable was set to a Python installation at an unusual location on the machine.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), PYTHONPATH is used as the import location when the module is not found in the current directory.

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - the installation-dependent default.

For some reason PYTHONPATH is not set/unset by the activate/deactivate scripts. It does set PYTHONHOME, but this doesn't seem to affect imports. This feels like a bug in virtualenv and pyvenv (I tried both).

The original activate.bat scripts change a "set" variable, which doesn't affect the $env:PYTHONPATH. Activate.ps1 attempts to save the original PYTHONPATH in a variable, set it to the virtual environment directory, then on deactivate, restore the original PYTHONPATH. Neither of these work anymore, possibly due to a Powershell or Python update.

The solution for us is to modify the activate and deactivate scripts (PoSh or bat) to switch the PYTHONPATH between two hard-coded values.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that looks strange to me is that you are running

```
D:\PyVirtualEnvs\example_py34\Scripts\activate.bat
```

in powershell when a there is a activate.ps1. I don't know if there are compatibility issues with this.

Comment: Thanks, good point, but I just tried it and got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a `cmd.exe` shell script from PowerShell (a batch file), PowerShell spawns an instance of `cmd.exe` to run the script (batch file). If the batch file sets environment variables, they exist only in the spawned `cmd.exe` instance. Once that instance terminates (i.e., when the script ends), the environment variables do not propagate to the calling process (PowerShell, in this case). This is by design.

If you want to propagate environment variables, you can use the following `Invoke-CmdScript` function in PowerShell:

```
function Invoke-CmdScript {
  param(
    [String] $scriptName
  )
  $cmdLine = """$scriptName"" $args & set"
  & $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe /c $cmdLine |
  Select-String '^([^=]*)=(.*)$' | ForEach-Object {
    $varName = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    $varValue = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    Set-Item Env:$varName $varValue
  }
}
```

Some more information about this in the following article:

[Windows IT Pro: Take Charge of Environment Variables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell)

In your case, you would run:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-CmdScript D:\PyVirtualEnvs\example_py34\Scripts\activate.bat
```

This will spawn `activate.bat` and propagate the environment variable changes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. However, the Invoke-CmdScript function seems to swallow all the output from python, even in the interactive shell. If I run the activate as suggested then call the python command it's still the wrong version of django, if I try Invoke-CmdScript python.exe the -c import fails.

Comment: Presumably I'd need to run everything I wanted through a single batch file call to preserve those environment variables between the activate and python calls.

Comment: You would not use that function to run python; you would use it only to execute the `activate.bat` script and propagate the environment variables it sets. Note that there is an `activate.ps1` specifically for PowerShell as noted in another answer.

Comment: Sorry, crossed, comments. Ran activate.bat with Invoke-CmdScript (seemed fine). Ran python call as above (still django 1.6.5). Same with activate.ps1

Comment: My answer is specific to running a `cmd.exe` shell script (batch file) and propagating its environment variables to PowerShell. I don't use python so I can't comment on the rest of what you're doing. It seems to me that you need a better definition of your specific problem.